# How to show Reservation Available time gap between 8am morning to next morning 4am in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Previously already have customers reserve times :

```
09-11
12-14
23-01

$shopOpenTime = 08;
$shopCloseTime = 04;
```

What is the easiest way using php to list out all available times?

```
01-04 / 08-09 / 11-12 / 14-23
```

Coding :

```
foreach($manyOldBook as $eachOldBook) 
{
    $availableTime = $availableTime . $eachOldBook['book_end'] . " - " . $eachOldBook['book_start'] . " / ";
}

echo $availableTime;
```

I tried :

1. using if else to convert 24 to 00, 25 to 01, 26 to 02...
2. using if else to check if $previous_book_end < 04, then show $shopCloseTime.
3. using if else to check if $previous_book_start > 08, then show $shopOpenTime.

End up there are more than 100 lines of if else statement, too messy code, too much code... I am looking for easier way to do it?

Maybe use php fmode()? [w3cschool fmode tuturial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_fmod.asp)

Or Maybe store all booked times in php array, and print value which is not exist in the array?

Any other creative and easier way to do it?

Comment: You should give concrete examples with inputs, outputs, and computing rules.

Comment: @JCH77 ok I have add concrete example for output, please check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use PHPs DateTime object for this. It will give you more flexibility, e.g. if your reservation is not a whole hour or things like that.

First convert your input data into DateTime object and the get the free blocks between.

Example:

```
<?php
$reservedTimes = [
    ['start' => 9,
    'end' => 11,
    ],
    ['start' => 12,
    'end' => 14,
    ],
    ['start' => 23,
    'end' => 01,
    ],
];

$shopOpenTime = new DateTime();
$shopOpenTime->setTime(8,0);

$shopCloseTime = new DateTime();
$shopCloseTime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->setTime(4,0);

$freeTimes = [];

//start of the free time block is the shop open time
$freeTimeStart = $shopOpenTime;

foreach ($reservedTimes as $reservedTime) {
    //add 24h if end is lower than start
    if ($reservedTime['end'] < $reservedTime['start']) {
        $reservedTime['end'] = $reservedTime['end'] + 24;
    }

    //end of the free time block is start of the reservation
    $freeTimeEnd = new DateTime();
    $freeTimeEnd->setTime($reservedTime['start'], 0);

    //add new element to array if start and end is not the same time
    if ($freeTimeStart != $freeTimeEnd) {
        $freeTimes[] = ['start' => clone($freeTimeStart), 'end' => $freeTimeEnd];
    }

    //start of the next free block is the end of this reservation
    $freeTimeStart->setTime($reservedTime['end'], 0);
}

//add the last element until shop closing time
$freeTimeEnd = $shopCloseTime;
if ($freeTimeStart != $freeTimeEnd) {
    $freeTimes[] = ['start' => clone($freeTimeStart), 'end' => $freeTimeEnd];
}

foreach ($freeTimes as $freeTime) {
    print('Start ' . $freeTime['start']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ');
    print('End ' . $freeTime['end']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    print(PHP_EOL);
}
```

This gives you:

```
Start 2021-10-09 08:00:00 End 2021-10-09 09:00:00
Start 2021-10-09 11:00:00 End 2021-10-09 12:00:00
Start 2021-10-09 14:00:00 End 2021-10-09 23:00:00
Start 2021-10-10 01:00:00 End 2021-10-10 04:00:00
```